# Where is angular "data" coming from

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**--- Given this code in a file ---**

```js
angular.module('storyCtrl', ['storyService'])

.controller('StoryController', function(Story, socketio) {

    var vm = this;

    Story.getStory()
        .success(function(data) {
            vm.stories = data;
        });

    vm.createStory = function() {
        vm.message = '';
        var newMessage = vm.storyData.content;
        var newStory = { str: newMessage , timeNow: new Date(), mess: "Hello" };
        Story.createStory(newStory)
            .success(function(data) {
                vm.storyData = '';

                vm.message = data.message;

            });
    };

    socketio.on('story', function(data) {
        vm.stories.push(data);
    })
})
```

Where does "data" being initialize or where is it coming from as it is not even a global variable or from ['storyService'].

Thank you

Comment: The data is an argument to a callback function - it's what the getStore() method returns.  What it actually is depends on what the getStory() method is doing, but given the .success() method, It's most likely doing an http call using the $http service.

Answer (score 1):

The variable data represents what the function (getStory or createStory or the on function) is returning to you for use in the function. For example, the getStory function might be returning a json array. Within the success function, this data is assigned to the vm.stories variable.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks... but i am just confuse that socketio.on('story', function(data) are able to fetch information from variable "data" without variable "data" being initialise

Answer (score 0):

The `storyCtrl` module references another module called `storyService`. Slightly confusing, the `storyService` module contains a service (or factory) called `Story`. The `Story` service provides a method called `getStory`. Internally `getStory` *very* likely makes a call using `$http`. You can tell because `getStory` does not use standard promises, but instead uses the `success` and `error` methods that [`$http` provides](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).